# Async. read from NetworkStream blocks for 60 seconds. (Rx)

Tags: c#, system.reactive, asyncsocket, networkstream

When there is no data in the stream and I try to read the stream blocks for 60 seconds.
When there is some data the read completes as desired.
How can I rewrite the following code so it can read only when stream.DataAvailable is true?

I think I need something like Observable.While(dataAvailableObserver, AsyncRead)..

```
    public static IObservable<byte[]> AsyncRead(this NetworkStream stream, int bufferSize)
    {
        return Observable.Create<byte[]>(
            o => Observable.Defer(() => AsyncReadChunk(stream, bufferSize))
                     .Repeat()
                     .Subscribe(dataChunk =>
                                    {
                                        if (dataChunk.Length > 0)
                                        {
                                            o.OnNext(dataChunk);

                                            return;
                                        }

                                        Debug.Assert(!stream.DataAvailable);

                                        o.OnCompleted();
                                    }, o.OnError, o.OnCompleted));
    }

    public static IObservable<byte[]> AsyncReadChunk(this NetworkStream stream, int bufferSize)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead)(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            .Select(cbRead =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data chunk received.");

                var dataChunk = new byte[cbRead];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, dataChunk, 0, cbRead);

                return dataChunk;
            });
    }
```

What I found is to read in small bufferSizes as the bigger buffers cause the waiting of the buffer to be filled (like in my scenario where the incoming data is small packets).

Comment: What do you want to to do when there is no data available (yet)? Wait untill there is data available or stop?

Comment: When there is data available to read it else to complete. The outer observer which accepts the data chunks polls the stream again for available data but the above part (AsyncRead) needs to complete when no data is available without issuing AsyncReadChunk.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Defer, you have to check for available data within your defer logic. The simplest way would be to do the check within the AsyncReadChunk method like:

```
public static IObservable<byte[]> AsyncReadChunk(this NetworkStream stream, int bufferSize) 
{ 
    if (!stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        return Observable.Empty<byte[]>();
    }
    else
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; 

        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead)(buffer, 0, bufferSize) 
            .Select(cbRead =>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is the code. Because after the initial 60 secs. blocking the next reads complete as desired even there is no data available.

Comment: That is because you are using Repeat. Repeat, repeats indefinitely, therefore the AsyncReadChunk method is basically called within an infinite loop. Which behavior do you want? Is your intention to read all the data from the stream?

Comment: @SametSorgut - Thats probably due to a timeout

Comment: I want to read the data in chunks untill there is not data available. My AsyncRead reads data chunks in bufferSize with AsyncReadChunk and checks if there is still some data available. If so keeps reading. When there is no available data it completes. The outer observer calls the AsyncRead again incase some data is received. This continues until user disconnects.

Comment: I added my polling code. It collects all of the read chunks and forms a payload...

Comment: So when should it stop? If DataAvailable returns false, that doesn't mean you are at the end of the stream. It can simply mean that you are still waiting for more data to come in. The fact of the matter is that you need a protocol in some sort to detect when all the data has been red.

Comment: Think of it as a game. It only ends when the client disconnects. There is always a data coming and going. For this i need one thread to read the messages. Don't think it as reading a single file from socket. Here data comes in intervals. When the servers sends a packet the client reads it until data available is false. Else it completes and its caller tells to look if there is something new arrived. This keeps going till disconnect.

Comment: In that case, the solution is easy. Set the Timeout on the NetworkStream to Infinite and simply perform a Read, just like your original code. Note that you may have to move your Select above the repeat statement

Comment: I use TcpClient and ReadTimeout is 0 (infinite) by default.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure as to if this will help, but this is the ToObservable() method I use to read streams.

```
public static class ObservableApmExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<byte> ToObservable(this FileStream source)
    {
        return source.ToObservable(4096, Scheduler.CurrentThread);
    }

    public static IObservable<byte> ToObservable(this FileStream source, int buffersize, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<byte>(o =>
        {
            var initialState = new StreamReaderState(source, buffersize);
            var subscription = new MultipleAssignmentDisposable();
            Action<StreamReaderState, Action<StreamReaderState>> action =
                (state, self) =>
                {
                    subscription.Disposable = state.ReadNext()
                        .Subscribe(
                            bytesRead =>
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                                {
                                    o.OnNext(state.Buffer[i]);
                                }
                                if (bytesRead > 0)
                                    self(state);
                                else
                                    o.OnCompleted();
                            },
                            o.OnError);
                };

            var scheduledAction = scheduler.Schedule(initialState, action);
            return new CompositeDisposable(scheduledAction, subscription);
        });
    }

    private sealed class StreamReaderState
    {
        private readonly int _bufferSize;
        private readonly Func<byte[], int, int, IObservable<int>> _factory;

        public StreamReaderState(Stream source, int bufferSize)
        {
            _bufferSize = bufferSize;
            _factory = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>(source.BeginRead, source.EndRead);
            Buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        }

        public IObservable<int> ReadNext()
        {
            return _factory(Buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
        }

        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have not tried it with a NetworkStream, but it sounds like you could swap the check

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
```

to

```
if (source.DataAvailable)
```

You would also need to then change the source type to NetworkStream.

I think the scheduling in my code may help you with your blocking problems. Another alternative, if appropriate (I still dont really understand you problem), is you could use
.Switch and create a nested observable.

This would mean when some data comes through you read it all off until it is done and then complete. Once you completed you start another sequence which will be any further data.

```
s1 --1-0-1-1|
s2          ---1-0-0-1-|        
s3                     ---0-0-1-0-1|
etc..
out--1-0-1-1---1-0-0-1----0-0-1-0-1|
```

s1, s2, s3 etc are the sequences that are a burst of data until stream.DataAvailable. Then these inner streams will complete, and kickoff a request (creating another inner observable sequence s2, s3, sN). The Switch (or Merge or Concat) all will be able to flatten these multiple sequences into a single one for your users to consume.

One other alternative that maybe easier to code is to have an IEnumerable<IObservable<byte>>. These are easy to create with just a method like this

```
public IEnumerable<IObservable<byte>> ConstantRead(string path)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return Observable.Using(
                () => new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None),
                stream => stream.ToObservable(4096, Scheduler.ThreadPool));
    }
}
```

***Change for your network stream requirements.***

You then just flatten like this

```
_subscription = ConstantRead(@"C:\Users\Lee\MyFile.zip")
                .Concat()
                .Subscribe(...
```

I hope that helps.

Lee Campbell